# PHP Global array

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I have a json_decoded variable that I want to be global because I need to do a match for that down in the code (in a foreach loop that inserts in SQL that value).

But the problem is after trying a few ways I am not able to access this `$uomlookup` value. It works locally but not globally.

What I am doing wrong?

```php
$inttrans = "SELECT * FROM mydb";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn3, $inttrans);

while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{

      $uomname = $rows['abbreviation'];
      $uomid = $rows['id'];
      $uomjson = array("$uomname"=>"$uomid");
      $uomencode = json_encode($uomjson);

     $uomlookup = json_decode($uomencode, true);
     echo $uomlookup['val1'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the code which you are showing working inside a function? If so then most likely you simply should return it:

```php
function myfunction() {
   //do your stuff
   return $value_of_the_future_uomlookup;
}

$uomlookup = myfunction();
```

Global variables USUALLY mean that you have a badly written code. YET STILL if you would like to make your variable global just declare it as so:

```php
function myfunction() {
   global $uomlookup;

   //do your stuff
}
```

If you have a different case then please provide a bit more info about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not using this is a function right now, but I tried and this didn't work (I may have this as $uomlookup['val1'] but val1 will be changed dynamically down in the code)

Comment: I still have an issue but I cannot access the variable, my json and array output look like [{"1":"ca"},{"2":"ws"},{"3":"or"}]Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => ca ) [1] => Array ( [2] => ws ) [2] => Array ( [3] => or ) )

echo $uomencode;
print_r($uomlookup);
How can I have the variable look for ca for example and return the id?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I assigned the json to a new array and I was able to use the variable